# If value is null waiting for run function in android

Tags: android, null

I run a class LokasyonBulucu()

```
LokasyonBulucu lokasyonBulucu= new LokasyonBulucu();
lokasyonBulucu.LokasyonBul(context);
```

I take two variable from this class lat and lon

```
lat=lokasyonBulucu.location.getLatitude();
lon= lokasyonBulucu.location.getLongitude();
```

but I want to waiting class found coordinates... because it take amount time.
if it find lat and lon I want to run this function

```
new arkaPlanIsleri(kategori_id, lat , lon).execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `for` loop to check every second with a maximum number of seconds to wait. Check every second if the `lat` and `lon` are already found. If so execute the method and break out of the waiting loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { //maximum 10 seconds to wait
    if(lat != null && lon != null) { //check if the lat and lon are already found
        new arkaPlanIsleri(kategori_id, lat , lon).execute();
        break; //stop the waiting loop
    }
    SystemClock.sleep(1000); //wait one second
}
```